# Comportamiento raro de MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

estoy intentando hacer una consulta a la base de datos para que me liste resultados cercanos al usuario (por latitud y longitud). Actualmente estoy usando una consulta que está en la documentación de Google Maps.
El problema está en cuando intento limitar para paginar (de a 10 filas). MySql me devuelve ítems repetidos en distintas páginas.
Esta es la consulta que hago:

```
SELECT p.producto_id ,
       (6371 * acos( cos( radians(-34.5996599) ) * cos( radians( p.producto_map_latitud ) ) * cos( radians( p.producto_map_longitud ) - radians(-58.5250757) ) + sin( radians(-34.5996599) ) * sin( radians( p.producto_map_latitud ) ) ) ) AS distancia
FROM productos p 
WHERE p.producto_publicado = 1
ORDER BY distancia ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Esto me devuelve:

[image: Resultados de la primer página]

Cuando paso a la siguiente página, ya se puede ver el primer ítem repetido:

[image: Resultados de la segunda página]

El script para la segunda página es:

```
SELECT p.producto_id ,
       (6371 * acos( cos( radians(-34.5996599) ) * cos( radians( p.producto_map_latitud ) ) * cos( radians( p.producto_map_longitud ) - radians(-58.5250757) ) + sin( radians(-34.5996599) ) * sin( radians( p.producto_map_latitud ) ) ) ) AS distancia
FROM productos p 
WHERE p.producto_publicado = 1
ORDER BY distancia ASC 
LIMIT 10, 10
```

De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: En efecto, eso se ve muy raro. De hecho, no parece estar respetando tu `ORDER BY`. ¿Puedes compartir algún script que nos permita reproducir el problema? O tal vez puedes usar http://sqlfiddle.com o http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler para montar una demostración del problema. La verdad, es que me cuesta creerlo. ¿Qué programa cliente estás usando para obtener los resultados de MySQL?

Comment: Ni la primera ni la segunda consulta están ordenadas de la manera en la que se pone. ¿Podría haber algún problema con el formato en el que se están mostrando los números?

Comment: Tienes algun indice en p.producto_publicado?

Comment: Estimados, después de leer largas listas de documentos resulta que mysql tiene una especie de "bug" que a su vez no es bug. La manera de resolverlo es el ORDER BY por distancia y a p.producto_id 
Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Hola Estefano. No nos puedes picar la curiosidad así y dejarnos en el aire :) ¿Tienes algún enlace que explique el "bug"?

Comment: @sstan este fue uno de los tantos (pero el mas claro) https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69732

Comment: Hola Estefano. Ese enlace lo había visto ya, pero a mi vista, esto no explica los resultados que obtuvistes, donde dentro de una misma página de resultados, los registros no están respetando el orden especificado. Pero bueno, de todos modos, el cambio que hicistes era necesario y me alegra que tu problema quedó resuelto :)

Comment: @sstan no, explica el problema de que repite resultados cuando implementa la lógica de paginado.

Comment: @EstefanoSalazar, te invito a que armes la respuesta, es un comportamiento  un poco "anti natural" de MySql por lo que seguramente la inquietud se va a volver a repetir y estaría bueno tenerlo documentado en So. Saludos